# Error en function query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me devuelve ese fallo en el siguiente código, parece que no está funcionando `mysqli_query()`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in
```

Creo que es un error sencillo pero no detecto ahora mismo donde puede estar el fallo, he visto ejemplos que son idénticos

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["register"])){

if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
$full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query=$mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
//$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows==0)
```

Fichero connection.php donde se observa que se conecta correctamente

```
* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
    // Check connection
if (!$link) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste que la conexión si funcione?

Comment: @BetaM Si, la conexión funciona, añado lo que incluye el fichero connection.php

Comment: sin duda alguna tu conexión no esta funcionando y derivado de eso obtienes null al querer procesar la consulta

Comment: @BetaM funciona, como indico en el codigo y en la siguiente imagen https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYoN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estableces la conexión en estilo por procedimientos y no por objeto:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Entonces, cuando intentas ejecutar la consulta, la variable `$mysql` no está definida:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
```

Debes ejecutar la consulta en estilo por procedimientos y proporcionar como primer argumento la variable que usaste para conectar:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
```

Consulta la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) para ver más información y ejemplos.

Comment: Exctamente, bien explicado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a probarlo. Tengo que refrescar bastante en PHP, muchos años sin meterme en esta tecnología. De nuevo gracias, pruebo

Comment: Funciona, gracias!